# Best method in writing a list to a text file in python?

Tags: python, text, spyder

```
import pandas
import sys
import os
import csv
import string

f=open(myfile,"r")
lines=f.readlines()
x=[]

for i in lines:

    x.append(i.split()[3]);


f.close()

if not os.path.exists(path):        
    os.chdir(subfolder)
```

method 1 : this one works, but prints the numbers with separated digits in columns as you see in the image here : .[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvVcM.png)

```
with open('x.txt', 'w') as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\n')
     writer.writerows(x)
```

method 2 : this one gives the error : 'list' object has no attribute 'write'

```
#for item in x:
#  x.write("%s\n" % item)
```

method 3 : this one works, but writes the list with all commas in one row, while I need a column of numbers

```
#file = open("x.txt","w")
# 
#file.write(str(x)) 
# 
# 
#file.close()
```

method 4 : Error : 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

```
for i in x:
    i.write(i, '\n')
```

mthod 5 : Error : name 'number' is not defined

```
with open('x.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write('%d' % number)
```

I am frustrated with these errors, I wanted to use python to save my time, I wasted all that time in debugging and now I am almost at the brink of finishing it. I will appreciate your attention.

Hi All

I have a text file that contains 7 columns and I need to write each column of numbers to a separate text file. numbers with many decimal digits. So I am trying to write to a text file from a list in python, as you see, the name of each corresponding list is the same as the text file it should be written to. 
 but I am not succeeding despite having tried several existing examples from the internet, and I don't know the reason of the errors.
Why not once for all clarify it?

Comment: Is `x` in your five methods the same as `x` as in the example? In other words, is it a list of number-like strings?

Comment: I updated my question : the name of each corresponding list is the same as the text file it should be written to. I have a text file with numbers with 7 columns , I want to separate the columns and write each column to a separate text file

Comment: You have to come up with a MINIMAL example. Surely, if you know how to write `x`, you also know how to write `t`, etc., and your example is seven tomes shorter.

Comment: I corrected it , thank you

Comment: Why do I get negative votes before any editing ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer DYZ, but just if possible , could you let me know why aren't the other methods working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are importing pandas, why don't you use it, too.

```
data = pd.read_table(myfile, header=None, sep='\s+')
data.columns = 't','x','y','z','Rx','Ry','Rz'

for column in data:
    with open(column + ".txt", "w") as ofile:
        ofile.write(' '.join(str(i) for i in data[column]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

So if i understand the filestructure you want correctly:

you want each line to have 7 numbers in order "t z y x Rz Ry Rx" with space between them.

First you need to go through first element of all lists, than through second, etc...

To do so best may be [zip (documentation)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:  # We open file for writing
    for line in zip(t, z, y, x, Rz, Ry, Rx):
        line = [str(i) for i in line]  # convert to strings
        f.write(' '.join(line) + "\n")  # joins space and ends the line
```

## EDIT:

Ok, so if I now understand the format, the following shoud help:

```
with open('x.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join([str(i) for i in x]) + '\n')  # omit "+ '\n'" if you don't want newline at the end of the file.
```

Repeate for each variable.

## EDIT 2:

My explanation for why your methods don't work:

> method 1

It's just how csv writer's writerows work

> method 2

you are doing for each item in x, where x is list, not file you can write to. Corrected code:

```
with open('x.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in x:
        f.write(str(item) + '\n')
```

note that '%s\n' can't work as item is int and s is for string, f.write('%d\n' % item) shoud work

> method 3

str(x) formats list to the form you see it in file and you just write that into the file. The formating can be seen by doing print(str(x))

> method 4

again same as in method 2

> method 5

Similar to method 2. You don't define number anywhere. For it to work use:

```
with open('x.txt', 'w') as f:
    for number in x:
        f.write('%d\n' % number)
```

Comment: thank you, but I have a text file with numbers with 7 columns , I want to separate the columns and write each column to a separate text file. this will write them all in one file

Comment: I modified this and succeeded 90% , there is still one space left between the digits :
http://i66.tinypic.com/1fcl05.png

Comment: this is the code :

with open('x.txt', "w") as f:  # We open file for writing
    for line in x:
        line = [str(i) for i in line]  # convert to strings
        f.write(''.join(line) + "\n")  # joins space and ends the line

Comment: I don't understand what output shoud look like, if x = [1, 2, 3, 4]; x.txt is "1 2 3 4\n" or what?

Comment: It should be one single column of numbers