# Adding an integer number to all elements of a list that are not integer

Tags: python, list, spyder

Method 1 : Error : ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('

```
x = numpy.array(x)
x_5= x + 5
```

Method 2 : Error : must be str, not int

```
x_5 = [x+5 for x in x]
```

Method 3 : Error : invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-0.081428368'
 I tried to convert the x data first to integer

```
x_int = list(map(int, x))

x_5 = [x+5 for x in x]
```

method 4 : Error : 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

```
x = numpy.array(x, dtype=float)
x = numpy.array(x)
x_piu_5= x + 5
```

Method 5 : Error : float object is not iterable

```
x_piu_5=[]
xfl=[float(i) for i in x]
x_piu_5[:] = [x + 5 for x in xfl]
```

Hi All

I am trying to add an integer number to my list which contains a lot of numbers like 0.00085695 , etc, and I have used two methods but I have been unsuccessful

Update 1 : Added method 4 , I have obtained the values I wanted, but the problem now is that it say the numpy.float is not iterable

Update 2 : Added method 5, Should I convert the float to string before iteration ?

Comment: `x = numpy.array(x, dtype=float)`

Comment: Error : 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

Comment: How did you run your first line of code and get a different error if `x` isn't even iterable?

Comment: I have mentioned the first error I have got, in front of each method I have used, and your method, gave me a new error, that I shared, I am not a python expert, and don't know why my list 'x' is or is not iterable

Comment: Well, do you know what `x` is? And what you're trying to do? That would be a good starting point, and you haven't mentioned either.

Comment: please check my previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48362364/best-method-in-writing-a-list-to-a-text-file-in-python/48362464?noredirect=1#comment83712014_48362464

Comment: now I am trying to add +5 to my list and then save it

Comment: But the error suggests that `x` isn't a list. Please `print(x)`, what is it?

Comment: x is a list of 30 thousand numbers like : '-1.002357837',
 '-1.032721873',
 '-1.056638952',
 '-0.997914311',
 '-0.897318956',

Comment: `x = [ '-1.002357837', '-1.032721873', '-1.056638952', '-0.997914311', '-0.897318956']; np.array(x, dtype=float)` Works for me, so there's something you've got wrong on your end.

Comment: what do you mean by the end ?

Comment: It means you think `x` is something, but it's something else.

Comment: you changed the numpy. to np. , the error for me : name 'np' is not defined,and I have printed x as you said and as it is

Comment: ... ... ... `numpy.array([ '-1.002357837', '-1.032721873', '-1.056638952', '-0.997914311', '-0.897318956'], dtype=float)`

Comment: You "list of numbers" is a list of number-like strings. That is why any arithmetic operation on them is impossible.

Comment: I have asked my question in details, but those people who give negative votes, can not get into detail of my questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core of your problem is that your list `x` contains *strings* representing *floating-point* numbers. You need to convert those strings to `float` objects.

More precisely:

- **Method 1** can be fixed by using `dtype=float`, as suggested on the comments:

  ```
  x = numpy.array(x, dtype=float)
  x_5 = x + 5
  ```
- **Method 2** can be fixed by converting the items of `x` to float values before adding 5:

  ```
  x_5 = [float(i) + 5 for i in x]
  ```
- **Method 3** can be fixed by using `float` instead of `int`, as your values are not integers but rather floating-point values:

  ```
  x_float = list(map(float, x))
  x_5 = [i + 5 for i in x_float]
  ```

  Note that this solution is equivalent to method 2, just a bit slower and more space consuming, as you are creating an additional list.
- **Method 4** can be fixed by removing the spurious `x = numpy.array(x)` line. You will end up with the same code as method 1.
- As for **method 5**, I suspect that `x` is not the usual list, but rather it's a float object.

Other than converting values to the correct type, another thing you should try is to use different variable names for different things. In your code snippets, you're using `x` both for your lists/arrays and for the elements of those lists. While it's not always strictly required, using different variable names would solve a lot of confusion and save you from many headaches!

Comment: Thank you very much, I have gone through all the methods I could , I was just not able to resolve the problem, I still get some unreasonable downvotes, it's like the members of the website think that everyone should be expert ! while I see very short questions with no detail getting very high votes, still can't digest this ! If everyone is an expert, there will be no need to a forum. now the problem solved